# sompy Module Import Error

Tags: python, module, python-import

I can't import the sompy module even though I installed it successfully, and it appears in the modules list of my python environment:

[image: my python environment isntalled modules]

When I try to import the sompy module using the following statement:

```
import sompy
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sompy'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Hey I got the same problem
I tried: cmd run python -m pip install -U pip

Comment: Where does the list `installed_packages` come from? Are you sure to run in the same virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Which interpreter/IDE are you using? If using PyCharm, the problem could be that PyCharm hasn't identified a root folder for your .py project.

I would try and recreate the root folder as a subfolder and right click > Make source directory.